# How does a call of property by another property is handled

Tags: python, properties

I would like to understand how a call of property inside another property function happens and how call order is done and sorted by Python.

For example:

```
class Amount(BaseModel):
    reserve: float = 0.0
    paid: float = 0.0

    @property
    def gross_paid_loss(self) -> float:
        gross_paid = self.paid - self.reserve
        return gross_paid

    @property
    def gross_incurred_loss(self) -> float:
        incurred_loss = self.gross_paid_loss + self.reserve
        return incurred_loss
```

So in this case how `gross_paid_loss` property is handled and is there any chance that this way of calling can cause any problem. Is there any better way to handle such thing? Calling a function through constructor and assigning them is one that I can think of.

PS: BaseModel is from pydantic for easy class writing

Comment: `gross_incurred_loss` is always going to return `gross_paid_loss - reserve + reserve`, which is to say, `self.paid`.

Comment: the method is called when you access the property, so when you access `amt_instance. gross_incurred_loss` ... at that point it will execute the code of `gross_incurred_loss` method line by line, which will then reach `self.gross_paid_loss + self.reserve` and at that point we access `gross_paid_loss` so that method will be called to resolve the value before adding it to `self.reserve`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think there could be a problem? Maybe Pydantic adds some functionality on top? I haven't used it myself. Otherwise though, property access works exactly like attribute access on the surface, and under the hood, it works practically the same as method access, so I don't see why you're confused about properties in particular.

Comment: As property act as descriptor object, I was not sure how python handled properties if it does any initiation or cached result in what order. My main issue was can it fail in any instance if other property is not executed before some other property ask for it. Thanks for the help now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works pretty much the way you would expect. You aren't mutating anything, so simple expansion gives you

```
incurred_loss = self.gross_paid_loss + self.reserve
              = (self.paid - self.reserve) + self.reserve
              = self.paid
```

Whether or not your *intention* is for `gross_incurred_loss` to return the value of `self.paid` (plus or minus a small amount due to floating-point precision issues) is another question.

If you are concerned about thread safety, then you can't necessarily predict what *either* property will return if you can't ensure that both instance attributes remain unchanged during the execution of the property getters.